# Designing the Kobuki Robot for desired navigation

Tags: c, navigation, robotics

We have been asked to design the C code for the robot to move straight when there is no obstacle. In case of obstacle, the robot is supposed to turn 180 degrees and turn left.

During hill climbing, the robot is supposed to be going uphill and downhill if there is no obstacle. In case of detection of cliff the robot is supposed to turn 180 and then turn left.

We have tried the code for the design asked. We have been able to make the robot move; the obstacle detection has been working fine. Even the hill climb is all good with exception of speed. But the cliff detection for some reason is stopping the robot altogether.

```c
/*
* KobukiNavigationStatechart.c
*
*/

    #include "kobukiNavigationStatechart.h"
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    // Program States
    typedef enum{
        INITIAL = 0,                        // Initial state
        PAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE,          // Paused; pause button pressed down, wait until released before detecting next press
        UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_PRESS,          // Paused; wait for pause button to be pressed
        UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE,        // Paused; pause button pressed down, wait until released before returning to previous state
        DRIVE,                              // Drive straight
        TURNL,                              /// Turn
        TURNR,                              /// TURN Left
        DRIVER,
        DRIVEFIX,
        TURNUPR,
        TURNUPL,
        TURNDOWNL,
        TURNDOWNR,
        HILLUP,
        HILLDOWN,
        DRIVEUP,
        DRIVEDOWN,

    } robotState_t;

    #define DEG_PER_RAD         (180.0 / M_PI)      // degrees per radian
    #define RAD_PER_DEG         (M_PI / 180.0)      // radians per degree

    void KobukiNavigationStatechart(
        const int16_t               maxWheelSpeed,
        const int32_t               netDistance,
        const int32_t               netAngle,
        const KobukiSensors_t       sensors,
        const accelerometer_t       accelAxes,
        int16_t * const             pRightWheelSpeed,
        int16_t * const             pLeftWheelSpeed,
        const bool                  isSimulator
        ){



        // local state
        static robotState_t         state = INITIAL;                // current program state
        static robotState_t         unpausedState = DRIVE;          // state history for pause region
        static int32_t              distanceAtManeuverStart = 0;    // distance robot had travelled when a maneuver begins, in mm
        static int32_t              angleAtManeuverStart = 0;       // angle through which the robot had TURNed when a maneuver begins, in deg

        int drive_state = 0;

        // outputs
        int16_t                     leftWheelSpeed = 0;             // speed of the left wheel, in mm/s
        int16_t                     rightWheelSpeed = 0;            // speed of the right wheel, in mm/s

        //*****************************************************
        // state data - process inputs                        *
        //*****************************************************



        if (state == INITIAL
            || state == PAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE
            || state == UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_PRESS
            || state == UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE
            || sensors.buttons.B0               // pause button
            ){
            switch (state){
            case INITIAL:
                // set state data that may change between simulation and real-world
                if (isSimulator){
                }
                else{
                }
                state = UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_PRESS; // place into pause state
                break;
            case PAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE:
                // remain in this state until released before detecting next press
                if (!sensors.buttons.B0){
                    state = UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_PRESS;
                }
                break;
            case UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE:
                // user pressed 'pause' button to reTURN to previous state
                if (!sensors.buttons.B0){
                    state = unpausedState;
                }
                break;
            case UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_PRESS:
                // remain in this state until user presses 'pause' button
                if (sensors.buttons.B0){
                    state = UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE;
                }
                break;
            default:
                // must be in run region, and pause button has been pressed
                unpausedState = state;
                state = PAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE;
                break;
            }
        }
        //*************************************
        // state transition - run region      *
        //*************************************
        //DRIVE until sensor
        else if (state == DRIVE && (sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpCenter| sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpRight| sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpLeft|sensors.cliffCenter|sensors.cliffLeft|sensors.cliffRight)){
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVER;
        }//DRIVEUP until sensor
        else if (state == DRIVEUP && (sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpCenter | sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpRight | sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpLeft)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVER;
        }//DRIVEDOWN until sensor
        else if (state == DRIVEDOWN && (sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpCenter | sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpRight | sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpLeft | sensors.cliffCenter | sensors.cliffLeft | sensors.cliffRight)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVER;
        }//DRIVE until decline
        else if (state == DRIVE && (accelAxes.y <-0.05 | (accelAxes.x < -0.05) | (accelAxes.x > 0.05))&&drive_state==1) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = HILLDOWN;
            drive_state = 2;
        }//DRIVE until incline
        else if (state == DRIVE && (accelAxes.y <-0.05 | (accelAxes.x < -0.05)|(accelAxes.x > 0.05))) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = HILLUP;
            drive_state = 1;
        }
        //DRIVEUP UNTIL FLAT
        else if (state == DRIVEUP &&  (sensors.cliffCenter | sensors.cliffLeft | sensors.cliffRight)) {(accelAxes.y > -0.05 && accelAxes.y < 0.05 && ((accelAxes.x > -0.05) && (accelAxes.x < 0.05))
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNDOWNL;
            drive_state = 2;
        }//DRIVEDOWN UNTIL FLAT
        else if (state == DRIVEDOWN && (accelAxes.y > -0.05 && accelAxes.y < 0.05 && ((accelAxes.x > -0.05) && (accelAxes.x < 0.05)))) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNDOWNR;
            drive_state = 0;
        }//TURN UP RIGHT 
        else if (state == HILLUP && (accelAxes.x > 0)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNUPR;
        }//TURN UP LEFT
        else if (state == HILLUP && (accelAxes.x < 0)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNUPL;
        }
        //TURN DOWN RIGHT 
        else if (state == HILLDOWN && (accelAxes.x > -0.01)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNDOWNR;
        }//TURN DOWN LEFT
        else if (state == HILLDOWN && (accelAxes.x < -0.01)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNDOWNL;
        }
    //DRIVE UP FROM LEFT
        else if (state == TURNUPL && (accelAxes.y > 0.03 && ((accelAxes.x > -0.01) && (accelAxes.x < 0.01)))) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVEUP;
        }//DRIVE UP FROM RIGHT
        else if (state == TURNUPR && (accelAxes.y > 0.03 && ((accelAxes.x > -0.01) && (accelAxes.x < 0.01)))) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVEUP;

        }
        //DRIVE DOWN FROM LEFT
        else if ((state == TURNDOWNL||state == TURNDOWNR) && abs(netAngle - angleAtManeuverStart) >= 180) {// (accelAxes.y < -0.03 && ((accelAxes.x > -0.01) && (accelAxes.x < 0.01)))
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVEDOWN;

        }//PART OF FIXED OBSTACLE AVOIDING
        else if (state == TURNR && abs(netAngle - angleAtManeuverStart) >= 90){
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVEFIX;
        }//PART OF FIXED OBSTACLE AVOIDING
        else if (state == TURNL && abs(netAngle - angleAtManeuverStart) >= 90) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            if(drive_state==1) state = DRIVEUP;
            else if (drive_state == 2) state = DRIVEDOWN;
            else state = DRIVE;
        }//PART OF FIXED OBSTACLE AVOIDING
        else if (state == DRIVER && abs(netDistance - distanceAtManeuverStart) >= 250) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNR;
        }//PART OF FIXED OBSTACLE AVOIDING
        else if (state == DRIVEFIX && (sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpCenter | sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpRight | sensors.bumps_wheelDrops.bumpLeft | sensors.cliffCenter | sensors.cliffLeft | sensors.cliffRight)) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = DRIVER;
        }//PART OF FIXED OBSTACLE AVOIDING
        else if (state == DRIVEFIX && abs(netDistance - distanceAtManeuverStart) >= 250) {
            angleAtManeuverStart = netAngle;
            distanceAtManeuverStart = netDistance;
            state = TURNL;
        }

        // else, no transitions are taken

        //*****************
        //* state actions *
        //*****************
        switch (state){
        case INITIAL:
        case PAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE:
        case UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_PRESS:
        case UNPAUSE_WAIT_BUTTON_RELEASE:
            // in pause mode, robot should be stopped
            leftWheelSpeed = rightWheelSpeed = 0;
            break;
        case DRIVEUP:

        case DRIVEDOWN:

        case DRIVE:
            // full speed ahead!
            leftWheelSpeed = rightWheelSpeed = 100;
            break;
        case DRIVEFIX:
            // full speed ahead!
            leftWheelSpeed = rightWheelSpeed = 100;
            break;
        case DRIVER:
            // full speed ahead!
            leftWheelSpeed = rightWheelSpeed = -100;
            break;
        case TURNUPR:
        case TURNR:
            leftWheelSpeed = 100;
            rightWheelSpeed = -leftWheelSpeed;
            break;
        case TURNUPL:
        case TURNL:
            leftWheelSpeed = -100;
            rightWheelSpeed = -leftWheelSpeed;
            break;
        case HILLUP:
        case HILLDOWN:

        default:
            // Unknown state
            leftWheelSpeed = rightWheelSpeed = 0;

        }


        *pLeftWheelSpeed = leftWheelSpeed;
        *pRightWheelSpeed = rightWheelSpeed;
    }
```

We expect cliff detection to result in turning 180 degrees and then turn left.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question? This site is not a debugging service.

Comment: @DelphiCoder I am alright with debugging; I want any hint if possible on what I can change to have reverse and left for cliff detection